# ReactJS — problems with detecting changes in state

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs, state

Checkout this example: http://codepen.io/lzhelenin/pen/jVbeRg

There's a small React application, it's initial state looks that way:

```
{
  foo: 123,
  bar: [{
    cux: 456
  }]
}
```

If you press the button, it adds a new object in state.bar and changes state.foo value. However if you press it and take a look at console after that, you'll see that state.bar of the previous state is exactly the same as state.bar of the new state despite state.foo is different. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Radio- mentioned, `_.clone` create a **shallow-copied clone**, so both the `prev` and `curr` state are both refer to the same array, so you better adjust your `clickHandler()` method to be like this:

```
  clickHandler() {
    this.setState({
      foo: 999,
      bar: [
        ...this.state.bar,
        {cux: 123}
      ]
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://underscorejs.org/#clone:

> clone_.clone(object)  Create a shallow-copied clone of the provided
>   plain object. Any nested objects or arrays will be copied by
>   reference, not duplicated.

So, `prevState.bar` and `this.state.bar`, which you're pushing new values into, are both references to the same array.